# how to move one folder to another folder in git hub?

Tags: github, xampp, github-pages

currently i am trying to upload my BCA last semester project data to Github so i can share it with my partners and easy to maintain but i got one problem, actually many problems but this is the biggest one,

i am creating one website which have use xampp so in htdocs folder which contain 4 folder like (admin,register,login,image) now i want to move login page to inside of admin page so it looks like admin/login/*

can anyone help to do this ?

(i am doing this on github online site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (i am doing this on github online site)

Don't. Github's web UI is not meant for moving files and folders around. Use the Git CLI, where it's as simple as

```
git mv login admin
git commit -m 'Move login folder into admin'
```

Comment: Thanks sir But CLI is not suitable for me because i am beginner and now i don't have much time to learn it  but i did it using downloading .exe version of github